# JavaScript keys() function why is there no documentation

Tags: javascript

I've spent about 20 minutes trying to find more information on the keys function in javascript...

I initially found the keys() function referenced in this answer:

[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array#answer-21656259)

```
hash = {"a" : "b", "c": "d"};
keys(hash); // ["a", "c"]
```

Does anyone have any more information on this function, especially browser support?

Comment: You are probably looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for Jonathan, Im looking for the documentation for the keys() function not the Object.keys() method or the Array.keys() method.

Comment: Well, look no further. There is no such function in JavaScript.

Comment: lol :) thanks Jonathon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such function, it's part of the console api

Description for chrome console: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#keysobject

For Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers

Comment: Yep, I've since tried this in a script and it throws Uncaught ReferenceError: keys is not defined

Comment: @Andrey, please don't answer documentation requests like these. Questions like this should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is not a documentation request. This isn't a JavaScript function and that's why there isn't any documentation.  So it's a valid question and the answer is valid, although perhaps the answer could be more explicit, (that would be a bit pedantic though).  However, I will delete this question if you think that it should be deleted. @Cerbrus

Comment: From your question: _"Where's the documentation?"_

Comment: @Cerbrus shoud I delete? Am happy to delete if that's your recommendation.

Comment: As the question currently is, in my _opnion_, yes. However, if you'd edit the question to be more like: _"What is this `keys` function, what does it do?"_, I'd say it has merit. So, focus more on getting an explanation for the function, instead of documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88713/discussion-between-chim-and-cerbrus).